# Negation Syntax Rules

Tags: discrete-mathematics

`¬(p∨q)∧(p∨r)` Does this mean the negation of both `(p∨q)` and `(p∨r)` or just `(p∨q)`?
If it was just `p∨q` it would make more sense to me being inside the brackets like `(¬p∨q)` but maybe that's just the programmer in me. I have also seen `(¬p∨¬q)` does that mean the same as `¬(pvq)` It starts to get rather confusing..

Does it have to do with order assesed for example look at `(pvq)` then its negation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the $\neg$ is applied only to $(p\lor q).$  If it was intended for the whole statement to be negated, then it would look like $\neg[(p\lor q)\land (p\lor r)].$  Now, for your second question, $\neg(p\lor q)$ is **not** logically equivalent to $(\neg p\lor \neg q).$  According to De Morgan's Law, $\neg(p\lor q)\iff(\neg p\land\neg q),$ and $\neg(p\land q)\iff(\neg p\lor\neg q).$  To check if this is really the case, let's look at the truth table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
p&q&(p\lor q)&\neg(p\lor q)&\neg p&\neg q&(\neg p\land\neg q)\\
\hline
T&T&T&F&F&F&F\\
T&F&T&F&F&T&F\\
F&T&T&F&T&F&F\\
F&F&F&T&T&T&T\end{array}$$
As you can see all the entries in the $\neg(p\lor q)$ column equal all the entries in the $(\neg p\land\neg q)$ column.  This means that $\neg(p\lor q)\iff(\neg p\land\neg q).$ For more info on De Morgan's Law, here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0):

The scope of $\neg$ used just before $($ extends to the $)$ which logically CLOSES OUT the grouping which was begun by the subject $($.

As to your comment about $(\neg p\vee\neg q)$, $\neg(p\wedge q)$ would be the proper way to move the $\neg$ outside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Usually negation is assumed to have rather high precedece, i.e. binds strongly to whatever stand to the right of it. So $\lnot a \land b$ means $(\lnot a)\land b$, $\lnot a \lor b$ similarly means $(\lnot a )\lor b$. Whether or not $a$ and $b$ are variables or themselves expressions is irrelevant, so $\lnot(p\lor q)\land(p\lor r)$ means $(\lnot(p\lor q))\land(p\lor r)$.

Finally, $(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)$ means $((\lnot p) \lor (\lnot q))$.

$\lnot$ is comparable to the unitary minus sign here - you'd read $-a+b$ as $(-a)+b$, *not* as $-(a+b)$.